# How to parse & detect Ansible playbook tasks?

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I would like to detect each separate tasks of an Ansible code to be able to make a process on the task that depends on its certain components. What I have tried so far to detect Ansible task is to perform `regex` match.

So, is there any supported way to get Ansible tasks with some libraries etc? If regex search would be a recommended method, then what would be suggested `regex` to match Ansible tasks?

Comment: Ansible playbooks are written in YAML. Use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) to parse them.

Comment: Can it be done with a regex? Yes. Should you want to? Mmm. Let me point out that this is going to be a long regex. Think of this: you probably want to catch the name from your playbook. For `tasks` there's a `name` defined as well, so you need to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply parsing the playbook as YAML gets list of tasks perfectly (thanks to comments).

```
import yaml

with open("sample_playbook.yml", "rb") as f:
    file_as_task_list = yaml.load(f)

for task in file_as_task_list:
    # process the task
```

As each `-` (dash) sign means to be another task in Ansible, it also makes the file list of dictionary items (tasks) when parsing as YAML.

Answer (score 5):

There's built-in `list-tasks` switch for `ansible-playbook`:

```
$ ansible-playbook --list-tasks test.yml

playbook: test.yml

  play #1 (test): test    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      command    TAGS: []
      debug      TAGS: []
```

If you need something more complex, use Ansible API to parse playbook and extract required data. You can start with [ansible-playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.3/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py#L180) example.